# Least Squares Revisited

Tags: least-squares, substitution

I am reading a paper on regression and there seems to be a simple substitution but I just cannot get my head around it.

My question is how you go from equation (3) and (4) to (5)? Please let me know your thoughts. Thank you!
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $(4)$, you have $x_i - X_i = -m(y_i - Y_i)$, substitute these back to $(3)$, it can be seen that
\begin{align}
d^2 & = \sum_{i = 1}^n [m^2(y_i - Y_i)^2 + (y_i - Y_i)^2] \\
& = (1 + m^2)\sum_{i = 1}^n (y_i - Y_i)^2 \\
& = (1 + m^2)\sum_{i = 1}^n (Y_i - mx_i - c)^2 \tag{$*$} \\
\end{align}
Now you might want to express $x_i$ in terms of $X_i$ and $Y_i$. By $(4)$ again and $y_i = mx_i + c$, it follows that
\begin{align}
x_i = X_i + mY_i - m(mx_i + c)
\end{align}
Solve this for $x_i$, we obtain
$$x_i = \frac{X_i + mY_i - mc}{1 + m^2} \tag{$**$}$$
Substitute $(**)$ back to $(*)$, it can be seen that
\begin{align}
d^2 & = \sum_{i = 1}^n [m^2(y_i - Y_i)^2 + (y_i - Y_i)^2] \\
& = (1 + m^2)\sum_{i = 1}^n \left(Y_i - m\frac{X_i + mY_i - mc}{1 + m^2} - c\right)^2 \\
& = \frac{1}{1 + m^2}\sum_{i = 1}^n (Y_i -mX_i - c)^2,
\end{align}
as desired.

It might be worth pointing out that this type of "Least squares" is not the conventional least squares that we are familiar with, it is called **orthogonal
least squares regression** in that we compute the distance from observation points to the underlying regression line perpendicularly, in contrast to vertically.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot!